# Cifrar datos enviados via axios

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

Es básicamente eso. Tengo una aplicación con javascript y por otro lado una api creada con Laravel. Ahora bien, ¿Como puedo enviar datos cifrados desde Javascript hacia Laravel, y de ahí descifrarlos de alguna forma para poder leerlos? Porque en la actualidad, mediante las herramientas de red desde cualquier navegador puedo ver que datos son.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Si estás usando ssl la información ya está cifrada, en el sentido que un tercero conectado a tu misma wifi no puede ver el contenido de la información inspeccionando los paquetes que viajan por la red. Tú puedes ver esa info en Chrome devtools, claro, pero es porque eres una de las dos partes del handshake. Si tú además quieres encriptarlos con un algoritmo que sea compatible tanto con el browser como con laravel, también se puede, pero significaría exponer una llave simétrica al visitante... El remedio es peor que la enfermedad